# linking the language tool to google n-gram dataset

Tags: languagetool

I was wondering if there is a way to force language tool to use google n-gram data set instead of its usual dataset? In fact, I think such a replacement would result in much more wise grammatical corrections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "usual data set" is mostly hand-written rules. So, no, you cannot use the Google ngram data for the rules. (Disclosure: I'm the LanguageTool maintainer)

Comment: I think that adding such a feature will enhance the abilities of this open source tool by several orders of magnitude! Therefore, I strongly suggest to consider linking them.